# Chisel 3 assignment to bit range

Tags: chisel

This seemed to work in Chisel 2, but doesn't work now:

```
class TestX extends Module
{
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val a = Output(UInt(width=2))
    })

    io.a(1, 0) := UInt(0)
}
```

Error: [module TestX]  Expression T_4 is used as a FEMALE but can only be used as a MALE.

What's the fix for this change?

Answer (score 8):

Chisel3 does not currently support subword assignment. That error message is pretty unhelpful though, I've filed an issue: https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/issues/399.

You can solve this problem by using extraction and concatenation:

```
class TestX extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(UInt(4.W))
    val b = Output(UInt(4.W))
  })
  io.b := Cat(io.a(3, 2), 0.U(2.W))  
}
```

EDIT: Updated with modern syntax

Comment: I am having a similar problem but I can not figure out how to solve it. Basically I want to connect a set of pins of a module to the output of current module. The connection part is :
 var right = conf.outputBits - 1 // Index
        conf.output.map{ case Config.Output(n,w) =>
                      io.outputs(right, right - w + 1) := pins(n)
        right = right - w
               }
I get the error below : 
(run-main-a) chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Cannot reassign to read-only chisel3.core.UInt@24f

Do you think is a way to specify the range on the output I want to connect ?

Comment: It's a little hard to see since comments don't allow formatting code; I'm assuming `io.outputs` is a UInt, so you can't do such subword assignment (as you noted). I think you should instead use the conf.output values to construct a `Seq` in the right order, and then `Cat` it all together. If you can post this as a new question with more of the code formatted, that would be helpful. You could so something like: `io.outputs := Cat(conf.output.map { case Config.Output(n, w) => pins(n).pad(w) }) // might be an issue if pins(n) has a width < w`

Comment: The basic idea when you don't have subword assignment, is to construct up a `Vec` or just `Seq` (since every field of a `Vec` must have the same width), and then convert that to a `UInt`

Comment: Yep, It worked like you suggested, with a small difference. Instead of pad(w) I used toUInt() becase on the case of pad, it showed the error "value pad is not a member of chisel3.core.Data". 
Thank you :D

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!